# Triple nested list fails

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, list

In order to have a list of the same type that  has three levels, you must indent it crazy, to the point of what should be (in my mind) level 5.

**Update:** Also note that I am not nesting with four spaces as outlined via the help page, and the first nesting works.  Also by design?

Basic list exhibiting bug (Ordered):

- Level 1

  - Level 2
  - Level 3
  - Level 4

    - Level 5

Ordered:

1. Level 1

   1. Level 2
   2. Level 3
   3. Level 4

      1. Level 5

Note that changing up the bullet type works:

- Level 1

  - Level 2

    1. Level 3

To me, it seems to be a bug, but maybe this is by-design.  I don't know.  These list rules can get complicated.

Source:

```
Basic list exhibiting bug (Ordered):

 - Level 1
  - Level 2
   - Level 3
    - Level 4
     - Level 5

Ordered:

 1. Level 1
  1. Level 2
   1. Level 3
    1. Level 4
     1. Level 5

Note that changing up the bullet type works:

 - Level 1
  - Level 2
   1. Level 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested lists have to be indented four spaces. That's what the in-editor help says, that's what  the [full help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-lists) says, and that's how the Markdown spec says it. Absolutely by design.

Comment: If that's the case, then why does changing the list type work correctly?  That's what really throws me off.  One way or the other seems to be buggy.

Comment: Also note that I am not indenting up to four spaces and the first nest works.  Also by design?  It's not so clear.

Comment: Agreed, it seems a bit weird (I had to look at the code to understand precisely why that happens), but the way this is implemented (in all Markdown ports), it's not easily changed. There are two reasons why I can live with this weirdness: a) If you just keep with the "indent four spaces to get nested lists" rule, it works fine, and b) both versions of Markdown that we use (the client-side preview and the server-side rendering) handle it identically, so you immediately see what your post will look like.